# PHP Multidimensional Array Combine Values With The Same Index Number

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0.6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.3
        )

)
```

What I wanted is to combine the values with the same index number. My desired output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5,
            [1] => 0.3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.9,
            [1] => 0.6
        )

)
```

I'm a beginner still learning the basics. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can start with a foreach loop, collect indexes in some array and then again loop and assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array `$res`, which will eventually hold nested arrays with your grouped values. Using `foreach` you can loop through each of your inner arrays from your starting array, and then for each inner array, loop through the keys/values in that. The key from the inner array is the index in the resulting array (`$res`) for which the current `$val` should be pushed into.

See code comments in the example below for further details:

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $inner) { // loop through each inner array `[0 => 0.5]`, `[1 => 0.9]` etc...
  foreach($inner as $key=>$val) { // for each key (0, 1, etc) and value (0.5, 0.9, etc) populate your $res
    $res[$key][] = $val; // append $val to the array at index $key, if the array doesn't exist, create it and add $val
  }
}
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
            [1] => 0.3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.9
            [1] => 0.6
        )
)
```

Click [here](https://3v4l.org/W2eZG) to see a runnable example

Answer (score 1):

If those index values are a fixed and finite set then you can simply do something like that:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [ 0 => 0.5 ],
  [ 1 => 0.9 ],
  [ 1 => 0.6 ],
  [ 0 => 0.3 ]
];

$output = [
  0 => array_column($input, 0), 
  1 => array_column($input, 1)
];

print_r($output);
```

Another approach for a dynamic solution is:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [ 0 => 0.5 ],
  [ 1 => 0.9 ],
  [ 1 => 0.6 ],
  [ 0 => 0.3 ]
];

$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
  $output[array_keys($entry)[0]][] = array_values($entry)[0];
});

print_r($output);
```

The output in both cases obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
            [1] => 0.3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.9
            [1] => 0.6
        )
)
```